Can Java stream pipeline definitions be prepared prior to evaluation?
I'm trying (and failing) to research something very specific. In code like
int[] nums;
// ...
String s = Arrays.stream(nums)
    .unordered()
    .parallel()
    .mapToObj(Integer::toString)
    .sorted(myComparator)
    .collect(Collectors.joining());

the Java documentation describes nums as a source, everything up to sorted as an intermediate operation, and collect as a terminal operation.
I want to pass the stream library as much of the pipeline definition as possible without giving it the source. Ideally, this would include the terminal operation, but even if it doesn't that would be a win.
The purpose is "second-order laziness": not only the usual evaluation laziness of streams, but to pre-traverse the pipeline definitions and potentially reduce them well before the pipeline is fed data. This is to reduce startup cost of frequently-called stream code, move the definition to a re-usable static final on the class, and be able to reuse and compose pipelines as objects instead of calling functions.
Picking on the API code itself, during this preparation phase I'd like for a method like IntPipeline.mapToObj:
private <U> Stream<U> mapToObj(IntFunction<? extends U> mapper, int opFlags) {
    return new ReferencePipeline.StatelessOp<>(this, StreamShape.INT_VALUE, opFlags) {
        @Override
        Sink<Integer> opWrapSink(int flags, Sink<U> sink) {
            return new Sink.ChainedInt<>(sink) {
                @Override
                public void accept(int t) {
                    downstream.accept(mapper.apply(t));
                }
            };
        }
    };
}

to actually be executed (directly or indirectly) prior to it having a source available. This seems possible at least in theory, because that code all seems lazy enough - it only spins up an embedded class that relies on some flags, not stream data contents. However, if I need to directly use this Pipeline class to do what I want, then it seems like I'm out of luck, since it's not exposed publicly.
In the ideal case, the final product would look like a static final object on the class that, with one or two calls post-construction, accepts the integer array or an early-stage integer stream (equivalent to directly after Arrays.stream()) and produces a string or a late-stage stream (equivalent to directly before collect()).
The nums example is a toy example, and obviously this strategy will have more benefits for some of the larger 20-line+ stream definitions I've seen.

The stream framework certainly does not support this use case, but it's not really likely to help you or especially performance in any meaningful way.

Just return it as a lambda.

You wrote:

This is to reduce startup cost of frequently-called stream code, move the definition to a re-usable static final on the class, and be able to reuse and compose pipelines as objects instead of calling functions.

There are at least two fundamental problems with this:

A Stream is not reusable. This is not about laziness or the point of data binding; the Stream API is just designed this way. You can use a Stream pipeline only once.

Your idea is assuming that there is a significant amount of preparation work going on that is worth optimizing. I can not see anything in the source code of the reference implementation that supports this idea. But if in doubt, use an impartial profiling tool to measure the actual work and identify the places where the time is spent.
If the preparation takes a significant part of the overall execution time, it usually indicates that you have not enough data worth using a parallel stream.


But to address your idea literally, you could use the following code:
public class PreparedStream {
    final Stream<String> prepared;
    int[] actualData;

    public PreparedStream(){
        this(Comparator.naturalOrder());
    }

    public PreparedStream(Comparator<? super String> myComparator) {
        // already implies .unordered() .parallel() ──────────┬──┐
        prepared = StreamSupport.intStream(this::spliterator, 0, true)
            .mapToObj(Integer::toString)
            .sorted(myComparator);
    }

    public String execute(int[] nums) {
        actualData = nums;
        return prepared.collect(Collectors.joining());
    }

    private Spliterator.OfInt spliterator() {
        return Spliterators.spliterator(actualData, 0);
    }
}

E.g.
PreparedStream s = new PreparedStream();
String result = s.execute(new int[] { 9, 8, 7, 3, 1, 2 });

The constructs the Stream pipeline while no actual data has been provided. However, as said, this doesn’t change the fact that a Stream pipeline is a one-time-use thing, therefore, an instance of PreparedStream also can be used only once.
Further, the stream pipeline prepared so far before execute is invoked, is basically a linked list. There is no other preparation work going on, as the final state, known only when the terminal operation is commenced, is the most relevant. For example, you can change between parallel and sequential as many times as you wish, the last state, active at the terminal operation, will determine the overall operation mode. Also, whether the terminal operation is short-circuiting or not, has one of the biggest impacts.
You can go one step further by executing the terminal operation in a separate thread, to stop it at the point when the spliterator is queried and some of the terminal operation’s preparation work has been done already, to wait for the actual start call providing the data.
public class PreparedTerminalOperation {
    final SynchronousQueue<int[]> actualData = new SynchronousQueue<>();
    final CompletableFuture<String> prepared;

    public PreparedTerminalOperation(){
        this(Comparator.naturalOrder());
    }

    public PreparedTerminalOperation(Comparator<? super String> myComparator) {
        prepared = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() ->
            StreamSupport.intStream(this::spliterator, 0, true)
                .mapToObj(Integer::toString)
                .sorted(myComparator)
                .collect(Collectors.joining()),
            Executors.newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor());
    }

    public String execute(int[] nums) {
        try {
            actualData.put(nums);
            return prepared.join();
        } catch(InterruptedException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
    }

    private Spliterator.OfInt spliterator() {
        try {
            return Spliterators.spliterator(actualData.take(), 0);
        } catch(InterruptedException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
    }
}

Still used the same way
PreparedTerminalOperation s = new PreparedTerminalOperation();
String result = s.execute(new int[] { 9, 8, 7, 3, 1, 2 });

But even now, it’s unlikely to see a difference in the timing regarding the work that has been shifted before the execute call. As said, I don’t see any work in the Stream implementation that could make a difference. Even if the object was reusable, which it still is not, there would be no significant saving.

The stream itself is not reusable, it is designed this way. What you can reuse is the strategy to handle a stream. For that you would need an abstraction. For the current example java.util.function.Function can be used.
Let's say:
public class StreamMapper<E, R> {

  private final Function<Stream<E>, R> streamHandler;

  public StreamMapper(Function<Stream<E>, R> streamHandler) {
    this.streamHandler = streamHandler;
  }

  public R invoke(Collection<E> source) {
    return streamHandler.apply(source.stream());
  }

  public R invoke(E[] source) {
    return streamHandler.apply(Stream.of(source));
  }
}

Usage:
Function<Stream<Integer>, String> strategy = stream -> stream
        .unordered()
        .parallel()
        .sorted()
        .map(Object::toString)
        .collect(Collectors.joining());
StreamMapper<Integer, String> streamMapper = new StreamMapper<>(strategy);

List<Integer> listSource = List.of(1, 3, 2, 6, 4, 5, 7);
System.out.println(streamMapper.invoke(listSource));

Integer[] arraySource = {1, 3, 2, 6, 4, 5, 7};
System.out.println(streamMapper.invoke(arraySource));

